# If $L_1,L_2$ are semidecidable, is $L_1-L_2$ semidecidable?

Tags: computer-science, computability

I am working on the following exercise:

> If $L_1,L_2$ are semidecidable, is $L_1-L_2 = \{w \mid w \in L_1 \text{ and }  w \not\in L_2\}$ semidecidable?

I think that the claim is not true, but I can not find an easy counterexample. I think using something like $A_{TM}$ as $L_2$ might work, but I do not know what I should take as $L_1$. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: How about just all strings?

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot, this solves  it.